# Field owned by nobody?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, real-estate, yovel, ownership

I feel like I should have seen this discussed somewhere, but I have no memory of it.

If someone dies with no sons and his daughters inherit his fields, one of the daughters marries a convert, and then she dies and he dies with no children, what happens to the fields at Yovel?

Does it go back to the original owner's family?  Does it become hefker every time?  Does it permanently belong to the family of the first person who acquires it?  Does it go to the kohanim like a hekdesh field that was redeemed by someone else or never redeemed?

Comment: Sounds like the classic case of a Ger passing away w/o heirs - his property is hefker and "first come first serve". Your scenario explains nicely how come he owns property. (Though there is a machlokes in a Mishna if inherited property reverts to the family in Yovel, but I think we pasken that it doesn't.) No time for sourcing it now.

Comment: @DannySchoemann The classic case is usually discussed with metaltelin (or the slaves discussion in kiddushin with Rav Mari).  That's an easier case to contract because the ger can just buy them and they belong to him forever, you don't need him to inherit from his wife. I don't remember seeing it with land that belongs to him as a sdei achuza.   I'm sure it becomes hefker initially, but my question is at yovel.

Comment: Nope. See סימן ערה - דין הזוכה בנכסי גר שנתגיר ומת בלא יורשין - http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01977_part_26.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2 - that it's mainly (or also?) about property.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I guess your "Nope" refers to the discussion of land there?  But it still doesn't mention Yovel, he's talking בזמן הזה.

Comment: @DannySchoemann plus even when Yovel is operational, most of the time a ger will only own sdei mikneh, the case I'm interested in is when he inherited sdei achuza.

Comment: According to those who hold *yerushath habaal* is *min hatorah*, it doesn't seem to make much sense that it would be any different than *mitaltelin* and should be *hefker*.  His in-laws are not his *yorshim*, and that's part of the *chidush* of *yerushath habaal*. 

Even according to those who hold *yerushath habaal* is only *miderabanan*, it sounds like they were *oker* the *din torah* entirely, and it should belong to his heirs (not hers) in prepetuity.  For example, even if he died with children (e.g. from another marriage) the same should apply.

Comment: @Loewian I agree with everything you said, but that doesn't answer the question of what happens in yovel when there are no heirs.

Comment: If it's *min hatorah*, there should be no distinction between an *ezrach* and a *ger*, which should mean it should revert to *hefker* if the *ger* has no *yorshim*.  So too if it is *miderabanan* assuming they only made the one *takana* for the sake of the marriage and didn't explicitly make a caveat for the case at hand (*milsa d'lo shekhicha*)

Comment: @Loewian that's not obvious to me.  As far as I remember it's always mentioned in the Torah from the point of view of the original owner (e.g. תשבו איש אל אחזתו).  Maybe when there's no original owner yovel doesn't do anything.